# How can I search for multiple values in one field with Angular JS filters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to let the user search for multiple values in 3 different search fields. Currently it is searching for the value `nombre` and I want to add another 2 fields to look for the values `codigo_interno` and `codigo_comercial` as well.

These are the `<DIVs>` I have:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                <select ng-model="categoria" class="form-control" ng-options="item for item in categorias" placeholder="Filtrar por Categoria"/>
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Filtrar por Categoria</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 search right">
                <input class="form-control has-feedback" ng-model="search1" type="text" placeholder="Buscar por Artículo"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 search right">
                <input class="form-control has-feedback" ng-model="search2" type="text" placeholder="Buscar por Código Interno"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 search right">
                <input class="form-control has-feedback" ng-model="search3" type="text" placeholder="Buscar por Código Comercial"/>
            </div>
```

As you can see I have one dropdown filter, but the next 3 MUST be empty fields that allow the user to look for `nombre` , `codigo_interno` and `codigo_comercial`.

The developer that was working on this typed this function:

```
$scope.show = function (precio){
            cumple_categoria = $scope.categoria   == null || precio.articulo.categoria == $scope.categoria;

            regexp = new RegExp($scope.search1, 'i');
            data = precio.articulo.codigo_interno.search(regexp);
            return data != -1 && cumple_categoria;
        }
```

It does work for the value `nombre` but, **how can I make the other 2 fields look for the other values? Is there a way I can make the same filter field search not only for `nombre` but for `codigo_interno` and `codigo_comercial` as well?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple:

```
$scope.show = function (precio){
        cumple_categoria = $scope.categoria   == null || precio.articulo.categoria == $scope.categoria;

        regexp1 = new RegExp($scope.search1, 'i');
        regexp2 = new RegExp($scope.search2, 'i');
        regexp3 = new RegExp($scope.search3, 'i');

        data1 = precio.articulo.nombre.search(regexp1);
        data2 = precio.articulo.codigo_interno.search(regexp2);
        data3 = precio.articulo.codigo_comercial.search(regexp3);
        
        return data1 != -1 && data2 != -1 && data3 != -1 && cumple_categoria;
    }
```

I just need to add 2 more variables for the RegExp and 2 more for the data and validate them, simple as that.